# Too tomatoey gravy?

Tags: flavor, tomatoes, spicy-hot, gravy, paneer

I saw this video. He is cooking Paneer Tikka Masala. He used 6-7 tomatoes to make gravy for the curry. My question is that, when I cook and add so many tomatoes its taste is too tomatoey. Am I missing something?

[Paneer Tikka Masala Restaurant Style | पनीर टिक्का मसाला | Chef Sanjyot Keer](https://youtu.be/fohA4X5pYSg)

Also I'm making paneer Tikka masala which needs to spicy. Is adding sugar to neutralize the taste of the tomatos good? (I've read somewhere adding sugar can neutralize the sour taste in the gravy) Is it the right approach?

Tell me in depth how can I deal with this situation. Almost every time I cook I face this.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I don't understand your question, how would you know what something tastes like from watching a video?

Comment: How is adding sugar or neutralizing the taste of the tomatoes going to help you make it spicy?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  In order for folks to help you, you need to more clearly explain what you are doing and what you hope to accomplish.  Also, you need to limit your questions to asking one question, not multiple related questions bundled together.

Comment: You also need to post a transcript of the recipe, for those of us who can't be bothered watching a 7 minute video to extract information we could comprehend inside 30 seconds when written. Also, if the video is ever taken down, the question no longer has any relevance.

Comment: @Tetsujin Updated please check.

Comment: @FuzzyChef updates please check

Comment: @GdD Updated the question.

Comment: You still didn't post the recipe, nor is there any way we can guess how "tomatoey" the one on youtube tastes.

Comment: This isn't answerable, if you don't like the taste of tomatoes then add less or choose a different recipe. We can't tell you what your tastes are.

Comment: It simply means that your definition of how much tomatoes are appropriate and the YouTube cook’s definition is, well, different. There’s no absolute value for flavor. Use less, if you want less. Caveat: tomatoes are the main ingredient in this recipe. You’ll end up with less gravy unless you amp up the other vegetables.

Comment: Prayas: answer posted.

Answer (score 5):

The video recipe uses a lot of tomatoes, and the resulting curry appears to be heavily tomato-flavored.  The quick paneer butter masala I make myself is very tomato-flavored, on purpose, because my sweetie likes it that way.

So if you want a paneer curry that's "less tomatoey", my suggestion is to use a different recipe, one with fewer tomatoes in it, and more onions and peppers.  Adding sugar won't help, unless the specific flavor you're trying to change is the acidity.

Answer (score 1):

You probably use different kind of tomatoes; his looks small and relatively "dry".

Sugar can help remove/reduce the acidity in tomato sauces; but that's just it, it won't change the "tomatoey" of the sauce.

Make sure you cook the tomato mixture for a while to reduce the liquid so that the resulting sauce is not too liquid and that every ingredients are well cooked before blending.

Answer (score 1):

Tomatoes being too tart can sometimes be remedied by introducing a different kind of acid that takes precedence on the palate.

A teaspoon of cane vinegar, or white wine vinegar, or sometimes even cider vinegar can "replace" the acidic taste that you get from the tomatoes. You're also going to need some good salt to make it all come together.

What can *sometimes* happen, practically speaking, is you taste a hint of the vinegar along with the savory parts of the tomato, but don't taste the acrid acidity that some kinds of tomatoes have. That taste is still there, you've just replaced it with something milder, so it's not noticeable anymore.

I've used this trick with a bunch of different canned tomatoes that I bought while living in various places in S.E. Asia (it was hard to get good fresh or even canned tomatoes in some places) and it works ... 85 - 90% of the time.

You may (as others have pointed out) also find some luck with a little sugar. If you don't want to put refined sugar in your dish (which is a perfectly normal thing to not want to do) you can finely grate some carrot on a microplane and let it cook in.

Comment: Note: Don't do this with distilled white vinegar, it's going to taste horrible. Use natural cane or something better.